# Ag-Grid React: Row Flash instead of Cell Flash

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In Ag-Grid,  enableCellChangeFlash={true} will allow cells to flash when there is a change detected.

Is there any way to flash the whole row where a change is detected?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot automatically flash the rows on change detection, but can be done with `flashCells` api of ag-grid. Here is an example from the documentation.

```
  onFlashTwoRows() {
    var rowNode1 = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(4);
    var rowNode2 = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(5);
    this.gridApi.flashCells({
      rowNodes: [rowNode1, rowNode2]
    });
```

This will flash 3rd and 4th rows in the grid. This api can be combined with `rowValueChanged` or `cellValueChanged` events of the grid to make the rows flash on value change of a row/cell.

Cell Flashing Documentation - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#flashing

Value change grid events Documentation - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#editing